# Pass a Typescript dictionary object to C#

Tags: c#, typescript

I'm trying to pass an object from an Angular application to our C# API.  I'm trying to figure out how the dictionary objects need to be formatted as parameters.

The typescript:

```
// how I'm building it
const changesetUpdates = new Map<string, boolean>();

changeUpdates.loadTenderChangeUpdates.forEach((element) => {
  changesetUpdates.set(element.Id, element.deleted);
});

//the object I'm passing
export interface ChangeUpdates {
  changeUpdates: ItemChanges[];
}
```

The JSON it creates:

```
{"ItemChanges":[{"Id":"123","deleted":true}]}
```

The endpoint:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateViewedAsync([FromBody] SetChangesViewedCommand command,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    return Ok(await Mediator.Send(command, cancellationToken));
}


public class SetChangesViewedCommand : IRequest<int>
{
    public Dictionary<string, bool> ItemChanges { get; set; }
}
```

When the endpoint is hit, I can see the object but the values are empty, so I know I'm getting the structure right.  Thanks in advance.  Updated to answer questions

Comment: Show the JSON that is generated.  I am assuming you're doing an HTTP PATCH or similar verb that accepts a body.  Also I suppose you're sending a JSON body.  Finally, I suppose you have in C# an action method with one parameter decorated with `[FromBody]` whose type is a class with the property `ItremChanges` you're showing.  Correct any of my assumptions as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass just an object, but be careful, you use the key on angular as a string, on an endpoint int

```
{"1": true, "2": false}
```

to endpoint

```
[HttpPost("UpdateItemChanges")]
    public ActionResult Update([FromBody] IDictionary<string, bool> itemChanges)
```